# RegularExpressionValidator Regex to validate IPs (one per line) in a multiline textbox?

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, textbox, multiline

I have a multiline textbox that should only accept IP addresses (one per line, with no separating character).

For example:

```
10.1.20.1
10.1.20.2
```

So far, I am using the following regex with a RegularExpressionValidator to validate the textbox, but it only works if a single IP address is entered on the first line of the textbox.

If a second IP is entered on the second line of the textbox, the expression validation fails and the RegularExpressionValidator's errormessage is displayed.

My Current RegularExpressionValidator is as follows,

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ErrorMessage="IP addresses (one per line) only please." ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationExpression="\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)" />
```

I'm not just asking for a correct Regex here (as helpful as that would be), but more of an explanation that would allow me to create a working Regex myself please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the whole text should match the regex expression. Your regex only matches an IP as a whole word. You need to replace `\b` with `^` and add a 0+ quantified group matching a newline + IP.

Here is an example:

```
^  # Start of string
 (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)
 (?:               # Optional - 0+ - group start
   (?:\r\n|\r|\n)  # linebreaks of various types
   (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)[.](25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?) # 0+ lines having only IP
 )* # Optional group end
$   # End of string
```

See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/tB8cG2/1)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation + answer. Also the site linked for the demo should help with any further Regex problems I have! :D

Comment: Yes, as far as the regex testing sites, please note that regex101.com treats the patterns as PCRE/JavaScript or Python regex, thus, if you plan to use server-side complex patterns that should support .NET syntax, use regexstorm.net or regexhero.net. Just note that line endings are different: at regex101.com the line break is `\n` and at the .NET regex testing site, it is `\r\n` (thus, if you need to test multiline string and test separate lines, `$` should be replaced with `\r?$`).